# Descobrir a classe do objeto em Java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Tenho um conjunto de funções para configurar um conjunto de parâmetros em Java do tipo assim:

```
public void Util.setParametros(Integer par) {}
public void Util.setParametros(String par) {}
public void Util.setParametros(Long par) {}
public void Util.setParametros(Double par) {}
public void Util.setParametros(Boolean par) {}
```

Agora tenho uma outra função que utiliza essa e que recebe um array de parâmetros com os vários tipos que tem.
Por exemplo:

```
public List buscaPorWhere(String where, Object[] parametros)
```

E eu precisaria saber qual o tipo ele é pra poder chamar o método assim:

```
Util.setParametros((Integer) parametros[1]);
```

Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode fazer usando `instanceof` 
Como tem poucos tipos que você precisa verificar pode fazer alguma coisa assim:

```
for(Object p: parametros){
   if(p instanceof Integer){
      Util.setParametros((Integer) p);
      //...
   }
   else if(p instanceof String){
      Util.setParametros((String) p);
      //faz algo aqui;   
   }
   else if.... //por ai vai
}
```

**EDIT: OPÇÃO 2**
Outra opção é procurar uma forma de utilizar o switch case para evitar os if encadeados. Poderia ser assim:

```
 for(Object p: parametros){
       String className = p.getClass().getSimpleName();
       switch(className){
          case "Integer":
             //...
             break;
          case "String":
             //...
             break;
            ....
     }
```

Comment: `getName()` não. `getSimpleName()` sim.

Comment: vou editar a resposta

Comment: E atente-se ao fato de Switch com Strings só funciona a partir do Java SE 1.7